# Is it safe to remove javascript source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a way to hide javascript source using jQuery by using this script.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){$("script").remove()});
</script>
```

I tested creating variables, changing is value programmatically, calling functions, and ajax and so far it runs smoothly according to what it is intended to do.

I asked this question to prevent future damage to the web site I am currently developing.

Anyone who found out and using this method?

Comment: Doesn't really hide the source, though. It still shows in "View Page Source".

Comment: Its trivially easy to work around this method. I wouldn't bother trying to hide the source like this.

Comment: If you *really* want to protect your code, then I suggest you don't deploy it.

Comment: You'd be surprised about how much no one cares about your code or wants to steal it. The type of person that would even be interested in it would know how to find it. I mean, "View Source" isn't exactly high tech.

Comment: the javascript "scripts" will still be with the browser, so whatever your *malicious* intent is, it won't work. I also don't need a browser to get to your page. I can implement my own HTTP client via native C libraries in under an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a way to hide javascript source

No, this does not hide javascript source code. It simply removes all `<script>` elements from the DOM.

> Is it safe?

For normal javascript scripts, that have already been executed, yes. You could damage other functionality that uses script elements, like some templating engines, though.

> I want to prevent future damage to the web site I am currently developing.

Don't damage it now! Omit this script.

Comment: I always use "Inspect Element" of a web browser so I thought it is same with Page Source. Thank you for the answers